# Cognos drill-through

Tags: cognos, drilldown, cognos-8, cognos-bi

How to strip off the first word from a measure being selected in a chart in a source report and pass it to a target report so that it is consumed by a crosstab in that 2nd (target) report?

So, for example, my Source report has a measure called [High Risk %].  I want to pass the first word 'High' to a target report so that it filters the Risk Level dimension to only show [High] risk level data.  The Risk Level dimension only has 3 values (High, Medium and Low).

This seems like it shouldn't be that big of a deal but I can't figure it out.  How to do this in a prompt macro?

Answer (score 0):

Create a calculated data item in the parent query which does this. Include it in the chart query, and pass that instead.

Comment: Hi Todd, thx for getting back!  But how would I add the cal'd member to the parent chart without changing the chart? The chart is the way client wants it -- series is even nested.  I can add it to the report query, no problem, but how can I pass it?   Now that I take a look I don't think you can even pass calc'd members or calc'd measures via drill-thru--they don't show up in the drill-thru definition drop-downs (unless I'm doing something wrong)?

Comment: Thats right, my bad. In a list/crosstab you could go to Query->Properties and include it, but there is no such thing in charts. So

Comment: Upon rereading I'm not entirely clear on your data. Are there 3 measures in the source report called Low Risk %, Medium Risk %, High Risk %? Or are these the values?

Comment: Wish I could include a screenshot--so basically I have a line graph and I had a measure called 'Measure Value' in the Measures field and Timeframe in the bottom Categories field.  Originally I had Risk Level in my Series but then client came to me and said they didn't want to see (Student) Values in the Measure (by Risk Level), they wanted to see the % of Students that were High Risk, Low Risk, etc.

Comment: So in order to answer that, I created 3 measures called High Risk %, Medium Risk % and Low Risk %.  In order to have all 3 in the line graph I created a set called 'RiskLevels' and put the 3 new measures in it and placed that in the Series.  So the chart basically has 3 lines with data points over each timeframe, one line for High Risk %, one for Medium Risk % and one for Low Risk % of students by timeframe.

Comment: My crosstab has Risk Level and is getting passed a value from one of the 3 measures in the RiskLevels set but because I'm only passing High Risk %, Medium Risk % or Low Risk % and NOT Risk Level (which is a dimension), I need to figure out how to determine which line the user selected and somehow pass that to my crosstab so it will pop it in place of Risk Level in the crosstab.  That is the crux of my problem!